# Update div with static html

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I've searched for the last half an hour trying to find a way to update a div with HTML content every ten seconds. Everything either is to with loading a file or just plain text. Heres what I have done so far but I think it is way off.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
     $("myad").html('<iframe height="98px" width="732px" src="www.eg.com/eg.html"></iframe>');
}, 10000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `myad` is class do `$(".myad")` if id do `$("#myad")`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
         $(".myad").html('<iframe height="98px" width="732px" src="www.eg.com/eg.html"></iframe>');
         // or $("#myad")....
        }, 10000);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#myad')` instead of `$('myad')` and you should be just fine.

Edit: Actually, `$('#myad iframe').get()[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);` would probably be a nicer solution for the reload.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to reload the iFrame, an easier way would be to just give the iframe an ID.

```
document.getElementById("myframe").src = document.getElementById("myframe").src
```